# How to include "start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050" in java?

Tags: java, distributed, corba

I am trying to learn how to use CORBA by example in this web site

http://www.cs.mun.ca/java-api-1.5/guide/rmi-iiop/rmiiiopexample.html

So in this example usually I should run command line to run orb

start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050

Is there anyway to include this in java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Runtime.exec(...)`, see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])), but notice that you are starting a Windows Service there, once you start it, it will stay active until you stop it explicitly.

Doesn't this ORB have an API for Java integration? That page talks about Java RMI+ IIOP(Corba) integration, if you can embed the Corba ORB in your application it would be way better than simply launching the server manually.

If i can recommend another ORB, you should look into [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/).

Comment: I am try to do that but it give me error "Cannot run program "start"

Comment: Don't just use `"start"`, you are one Windows, use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd /c start orbd","-ORBInitialPort", "1050"});`, it should work.

Comment: Added full command above, not sure if start and orbd should be separated in two strings.

Comment: thank you but I use this and it work Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050");